# Para verificar se um arquivo foi modificado, tem técnica mais adequada que um pooling?

Tags: c#, .net, sistema-de-arquivos

Compensa ficar verificando por um ou mais arquivos para ver se houve alguma modificação e assim ter alguma ação na aplicação, ou tem uma forma melhor?

Comment: voce aceitaria uma solução com `nodemon`?

Comment: Não conheço, mas poderia, só acho que não é para usar com C#, conforme a tag da pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O *pooling* pode funcionar, mas não costuma ser o mais adequado. Em geral o sistema operacional tem uma forma de avisar isso para aplicação desde que peça para ele, e o .NET tem classe para isso, no caso a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

Há alguma controvérsia sobre seu uso, que ele não é perfeito e não é tão fácil de usar, mas funciona bem na maioria das situações e em todas se souber o que fazer. Por exemplo é complicado fazer isso pela rede. Sistema de arquivos pela rede nunca funcionou em sistema operacional algum. Tenha em mente que [existem alguns tipos de mudanças em arquivos que nem o sistema de arquivos fica sabendo](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110812-00/?p=9913).

A documentação mostra que ele se vale do sistema de eventos do .NET e você pode vincular métodos para fazer o que deseja em cima de eventos específicos dedicados a cada tipo de alteração.

Pode-se notar lá que pode escolher quais são os tipos de arquivos que deseja observar, até mesmo pode ser um só. E pode dizer que tipos de alterações realizadas deseja notificação.